# Pass locale string to Lang::get method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to send some localized notifications to my users on a react-native app with laravel backend, I store user language as string, like "es" or "en", now in my controllers I use Lang::get method, but afaik this always returns the server or app locale and not user's locale (which they can change from app settings).

So the question is, can I pass user locale from frontend to my server Lang::get method?

My code:

```
$body = Lang::get('newMatchBody', [ 'userName' => $this->receiver['name'] ]);
```

Comment: Can you not just call `app()->setLocale('es')` before calling `Lang::get()`?

Comment: Or, if you look at the documentation, `Lang::get()` accepts a 3rd parameter for Locale: https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Lang.html#method_get, so `Lang::get('newMatchBody', ['userName' => $this->receiver['name']], 'es');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get()` method accept lang code at the third parameter

```
Lang::get('newMatchBody', [ 'userName' => $this->receiver['name'] ],'en');
```